# Recursion function still runs after I tell it to return

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, permutation

I have this function that recursively checks and returns a list of permutations, but even when I tell it to return it keeps running?  I feel like I might be missing something obvious. (Also in python 3)

```
def createperm(ran: int, numints: int):
    acceptlsts = []

    def recursivechecker(lst):
        try:
            print("start")
            if lst == []:
                print(acceptlsts)
                lst == []
                return acceptlsts
            print("done checking if done")
            lst[-1] = lst[-1] + 1
            print("iterated last digit, %s is now %s" % (lst[:-1] + [lst[-1] -1] , lst))
            while lst[-1] in lst[:-1] or lst[-1] >= ran + 1:
                if lst[-1] >= ran + 1:
                    print("this number exceeds limits, going back")
                    lst = lst[:-1]
                    recursivechecker(lst)
                else:
                    print("this number isn't valid, trying next")
                    lst[-1] = lst[-1] + 1
            if len(lst) == numints:
                print("this solution is good, adding %s" % lst)
                templst = lst + []
                acceptlsts.append(templst)
                recursivechecker(lst)
            print("not long enough, adding dummy and testing that number")
            lst = lst + [0]
            print(lst)
            recursivechecker(lst)
        except IndexError:
            print("hi")
            return acceptlsts

    x = recursivechecker([0])
    print("yay", x)

createperm(5, 3)
```

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Comment: `return` doesn't return all the way to the top-level call, only to the caller. You probably want `return recursivechecker(lst)`, or at least you want to do something with the return value instead of simply ignoring it.

Comment: can you give some expected input and output for `createperm` ? what does `ran` means?

Comment: That said, calling the function recursively with the exact same argument you were originally called with is an indication that you just want an infinite loop to do the iteration, rather than using recursion. Python doesn't handle recursion efficiently, and it should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Wrapping such a large chunk in a `try`/`except` is also pretty suspicious. Try to flatten your blocks and use helper functions--a good linter will complain about the cognitive load needed to understand the control flow. No function should `print` something as a side effect unless that's the only thing it's responsible for doing. Throw errors or use return values to communicate with the caller programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your weak spot is your use of the free variable `acceptlsts` to collect results instead of simply dealing with what `recursivechecker()` returns.  It took me a while to figure out what your code was trying to do, I hope I got this right:

```
def createperm(ran, numints):

    def recursivechecker(lst):

        if not lst:
            return []

        lst[-1] += 1

        # iterate last digit
        while lst[-1] > ran or lst[-1] in lst[:-1]:
            if lst[-1] > ran:
                #  this number exceeds limits, going back
                return recursivechecker(lst[:-1])

            # this number isn't valid, trying next
            lst[-1] += 1

        if len(lst) == numints:
            # this solution is good
            return [lst] + recursivechecker(list(lst))  # use a copy of lst

        # not long enough, adding dummy and testing that number
        return recursivechecker(lst + [0])

    return recursivechecker([0])
```

**USAGE**

```
>>> createperm(5, 2)
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 1], [3, 2],
[3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 5], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4]]
>>>
```

I'd say you were close but needed to step back, clean up your code and account for everything properly.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!  That's helped me out a lot.  I feel smarter already!